# Linux confused by identical mounts on different disks after attaching disk

Tags: linux, mount, nixos

We are having a weird problem when attaching an EBS volume to a running Linux (NixOS in this case) instance (for the purpose of growing the file system on that attached volume; on it is the NixOS root file system for another machine that we shut down).

Before the attach ing, all is normal:

```
# lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0  100G  0 disk
└─xvda1 202:1    0  100G  0 part
```

After the attaching, `lsblk` oddly claims that the attached volume's partition contains the mounted `/` partition of the current machine:

```
# lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0  100G  0 disk
└─xvda1 202:1    0  100G  0 part /nix/store
xvdf    202:80   0  400G  0 disk
└─xvdf1 202:81   0  200G  0 part /
```

This makes no sense at all:

Just "plugging in" that disk makes Linux think that the root file system mount just "flipped over" to the new disk. The `/nix/store` (which is a NixOS read-only bind mount) remains on the proper disk somehow.

There are no messages in `dmesg`/`journalctl` beyond Linux noticing that a disk was attached:

```
Apr 28 11:57:21 mymachine kernel: blkfront: xvdf: barrier or flush: disabled; persistent grants: disabled; indirect descriptors: enabled;
Apr 28 11:57:21 mymachine kernel:  xvdf: xvdf1
```

In `fdisk -l`, the two disks look normal, and have different `Disk identifier`s.

It is impossible to `umount /dev/xvdf1`; it says the mount is busy.

For the goal of growing the partition, `growpart /dev/xvdf 1` works anyway, but `resize2fs /dev/xvdf1` fails with:

```
Filesystem at /dev/xvdg1 is mounted on /; on-line resizing required
old_desc_blocks = 25, new_desc_blocks = 50
resize2fs: No space left on device While checking for on-line resizing support
```

What's going on here, why does Linux confuse these disks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The reason is `by-label` mounts.**

For reasons of declarative automation (we have many machines), each of our machine's root file systems has the same ext4 file system label `nixos`:

```
# cat /etc/fstab
/dev/disk/by-label/nixos / ext4 x-nixos.autoresize 0 1
```

```
# cat /etc/mtab
/dev/disk/by-label/nixos /nix/store ext4 rw,relatime 0 0
```

Attaching two of those to the same machine confuses Linux.

So the solutions are:

- Do the file system growing by attaching the EBS volume to an AWS machine whose root file system is not mounted `by-label` with the same label.
- Change the file system label first, then do the change, then change it back to the desired one.